# Form binding for showing errors of a list

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've got a `Product` object that contains a `Set<Provider> providers`. I've annotated within the Provider a variable `url` with `@NotEmpty` and now I want to display a error, if this field is empty.
I'm not sure how I can access the field `providers` within the `hasErrors` method properly.

Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveDetails}" th:object="${selectedProduct}" method="post">

  <!-- bind each input field to list (working) -->
  <input th:each="provider, status : ${selectedProduct.providers}"
         th:field="*{providers[__${status.index}__].url}" />

  <!-- all the time 'false' -->
  <span th:text="'hasErrors-providers=' + ${#fields.hasErrors('providers')}"></span>
  <span th:text="'hasErrors-providers[0].url=' + ${#fields.hasErrors('providers[0].url')}"></span>

  <!-- not working -->
  <span class="help-block" th:each="provider, status : ${selectedProduct.providers}" 
     th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('providers[__${status.index}__].url')}" 
     th:errors="${providers[__${status.index}__].url}">Error Url
  </span>

  <!-- print errors (just for testing purpose) -->
    <ul>
      <li th:each="e : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}">
        <span th:text="${e.fieldName}">The field name</span>|
        <span th:text="${e.code}">The error message</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

Within the `<ul>` I receive for each error `providers[].url` as `e.fieldName`. I thought it would be having some indices like `providers[0].url` etc.
So my question is, how can I access the field `providers` within the `hasErrors` method properly to display the error messages.

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("selectedProduct") final Product selectedProduct,
                          final BindingResult bindingResult, SessionStatus status) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "templates/details";
    }
    status.setComplete();
    return "/templates/overview";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use <form:form> tags?

Comment: @Iker Obregon Reigosa: Because I'm using Thymeleaf...however, how would the `<form:form>` tag help me with my problem?

Comment: @randon66 I would do something like this.
`<form:form  id ="formulario" action="/saveDetails" method="POST" modelAttribute="selectedProduct">
 <c:forEach var="provider" items="${selectedProduct.providers }">
  <form:input path="provider.url"/>
  <form:errors path="provider.url" cssClass="error"/>
 </c:forEach>
</form:form>`

Comment: Okay, but mixing Thymeleaf with JSP (JSTL etc.) isn't a good idea, isn't it?

Comment: is the ModelAttribute in the Controller annotated with the correct name? The errors won't be available if the name of the attribute and the object don't match. See: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Fields-object-functions-Spring-td3302513.html

Comment: @Andrew: I think the validation works fine, because the `#fields.detailedErrors()` prints the errors. I've added the controller code in opening post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get an item from a `Set` using their index because sets don't have ordering. `Set` interface doesn't provide a method of getting an item based on index, so doing `.get(index)` to a `Set` will give you compile error. Use `List` instead. This way, you can access the objects using their index.

So change `Set<Provider> providers` to :

```
@Valid
List<Provider> providers;
```

Don't forget the `@Valid` annotation so that it will cascade down to the child objects.

Also, if `th:errors` is inside a form, it should be pointing to a property of the object that backs that form, using Selection Expression (`*{...}`)

```
<span class="help-block" th:each="provider, status : ${selectedProduct.providers}" 
    th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('providers[__${status.index}__].url')}" 
    th:errors="*{providers[__${status.index}__].url}">Error Url
</span>
```

### EDIT

I see that you want to access the errors collectively, instead of iterating through them. In that case, you can create your custom JSR 303 validator. See the following useful code fragments :

**Usage**

```
@ProviderValid
private List<Provider> providers;
```

**ProviderValid annotation**

```
//the ProviderValid annotation.
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ProviderValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ProviderValid {
    String message() default "One of the providers has invalid URL.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**ConstraintValidator**

```
public class ProviderValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProviderValid, List<Provider>>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(ProviderValid annotation) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<Provider> value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        //...
        //validate your list of providers here
        //obviously, you should return true if it is valid, otherwise false.
        //...

        return false;
    }
}
```

After doing these, you can easily get the default message you specified in the `@ProviderValid` annotation if `ProviderValidator#isValid` returns false by simply doing `#fields.hasErrors('providers')`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But is there a way to access the errors using the `#fields.hasErrors('providers')` method? Because this doesn't work for me...but showing errors for each index is working now using a `List`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!